# Troca de informações entre RecycleViews

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

Tenho abas de solicitações na qual a "RECEBIDA" recupera dados do BD Firebase dentro de um RecycleView.  Solicitação essa feita por um usuário e recebida pela empresa. Agora como faço os itens abaixo:

1 - O representante da empresa clicar em um item da solicitação recebida aparecer um AlertDialog se irá atender ou não a solicitação.

2 - Se atender, excluir o item de "RECEBIDAS" e aparecer em "ATENDIDAS".Se não, aparecer em "PENDENTES".

Se possível queria notificar o usuário também sobre essas ações.

Desde já agradeço quem poder ajudar. Segue meu código atual.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
    public class SolicRecebidaFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerViewListaSolicitacao;
private DatabaseReference refSolicitacao, database ;
private AdapterSolicitacoes adapter;
private ArrayList<DadosSolicitacao> listaSolicitacoes = new ArrayList<>();
private ValueEventListener valueEventoSolicitacao;
private String idUsuario;


public SolicRecebidaFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_solicitacao_recebida, container, false);

    //Config.Inciais
    recyclerViewListaSolicitacao = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_ListaSolicitacao);

    //Config.Referenciar nó de recuperação dos dados
   // idUsuario = IdUsuarioFirabase.getIdentificadorUsuario();
    database = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseDataBase();
    refSolicitacao = database
            .child("solicitacao_coleta");

    //Config.Adapter
    adapter = new AdapterSolicitacoes(listaSolicitacoes, getActivity());

    //Config.RecyclerView
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerViewListaSolicitacao.setLayoutManager( layoutManager);
    recyclerViewListaSolicitacao.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewListaSolicitacao.addItemDecoration( new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), LinearLayout.VERTICAL));
    recyclerViewListaSolicitacao.setAdapter( adapter );

    //Evento de click
    recyclerViewListaSolicitacao.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), recyclerViewListaSolicitacao,
                    new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item clicado",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item pressionado",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                        }
                    })
    );

return view;
}

@Override //Exibi lista ao carregar o fragment
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    recuperarSolicitacao();
}

@Override // Remove lista ao sair do fragment
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    refSolicitacao.removeEventListener(valueEventoSolicitacao);
}

public void recuperarSolicitacao (){

   valueEventoSolicitacao =  refSolicitacao.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            listaSolicitacoes.clear();

            for ( DataSnapshot dados: dataSnapshot.getChildren() ){

               // Log.i("DADOS COLETA FIREBASE", dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());

                DadosSolicitacao solicitacao = dados.getValue(DadosSolicitacao.class);
                listaSolicitacoes.add( solicitacao );

            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Para isso você vai precisar de duas coisas.

Primeiro: Modificar o código do seu aplicativo.
Toda hora que uma solicitação for atendida, você deverá removê-la do conjunto recebidas e colocá-la no conjunto atendidas. Ou seja, deixe o Firebase fazer as atualizações para você.

Segundo: As notificações você pode criar uma Firebase Cloud Function e toda vez que um item for adicionado ao conjunto atendidas, você envia uma notificação para o usuário em questão.

Evite fazer comunicações entre abas. Elas costumam sem mais lentas. E de qualquer forma, você já precisa atualizar o banco de dados.